# Running the bevy breakout example in WSL

Tags: ubuntu, rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bevy

I am trying to run the bevy breakout example on a Windows PC with Ubuntu inside a WSL shell. I followed the bevy quick start guide. But I get this error:

Command:

```
cargo run --example breakout
```

Message:

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.09s
     Running `/home/JohnDoe/bevy_example/bevy/target/debug/examples/breakout`
thread 'main' panicked at crates/bevy_winit/src/lib.rs:136:14:
Failed to build event loop: Os(OsError { line: 786, file: "/home/JohnDoe/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/winit-0.29.14/src/platform_impl/linux/mod.rs", error: Misc("neither WAYLAND_DISPLAY nor WAYLAND_SOCKET nor DISPLAY is set.") })
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

It looks like the display is not configured right. How do I do that?

The output of

`wsl -l -v`

is

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04           Stopped         2
```

Comment: cargo run --example breakout --features wayland does not working neither --features x11

Comment: I'll try to take a look at this, but can you [Edit your question](/posts/78136710/edit) to include the output of `wsl.exe --version`?  If it just returns the help text, then that's useful information as well. Also `wsl -l -v` could tell us something. Thanks!

Comment: ```wsl.exe --version``` does not work for me.. Do you mean the windows version ```ver``` command?

```Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155]```

I added the output of the ```wsl -l-v``` command to the description of the Problem

Comment: No worries - like I said, if it just returned the help text, that tells us something as well.  You're on an older version.  However, even the WSL2 that is in your Windows 11 build should support WSLg.  Can you try installing and running `xterm`?  I have a feeling you'll get a `DISPLAY` error there as well.

Comment: Side note - you can upgrade to the latest WSL version by installing from the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage), but I don't think that's going to resolve the issue (yet it may).

Comment: I've tried to reproduce on the latest WSL, and while I don't get the `DISPLAY` problem, I'm still not successful with running that example due to other problems, apparently, that I haven't figured out yet.  That's probably going to be a separate question for you to post once we get this one figured out.

Comment: you need to install missing packages...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257124/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-outofcoffeeexception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> Side note - you can upgrade to the latest WSL version by installing from the [Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage), but I don't think that's going to resolve the issue (yet it may) - NotTheDr01ds

Installing the new WSL from the Microsoft Store did fix the problem! Thank you!